# Download file from Google Drive with the discovery API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the following methods across my app to interact with numerous Google Discovery-based APIs:

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
    sys.argv, 'drive', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, 
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
try:
    self.data = service.files().get(
        fileId = file_id
        ).execute()

except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

However, in order to download the file, I need to add the "alt='media'" param to the URL. I've not been able to find any documentation on how to do it through this kind of implementation. I've tried using the "export" method, but that only works for Google Docs, not other types of file (mine is a CSV).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Downloading a file using alt=media](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

> To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the
>   file's resource URL and include the query parameter `alt=media`.

For example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

Here's a snippet for Python:

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

In case you're interested with direct download links for CSVs, you can also try [this guide](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/).

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```